# How to write upgradable smart contracts in rust (changing the storage)?

Tags: ink, openbrush

I am writing a smart contract in Rust using the Openbrush library. I am using version 3.0.0.

```rust
pub const STORAGE_KEY: u32 = openbrush::storage_unique_key!(metaData);
#[openbrush::upgradeable_storage(STORAGE_KEY)]
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct metaData {
        
}
```

```rust
#[ink(storage)]
#[derive(Default, Storage)]
pub struct PeerNftcontract {
    #[storage_field]
    data: metaData
}
```

I am using this code for changing the storage in upgradable smart contracts.
and whatever field I have to change I am writing in the metaData struct.
but it was not working.
can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://use.ink/basics/upgradeable-contracts/ ?

Comment: yes, I have seen the documentation but they have not written much there.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clear what you are asking at the moment

Comment: Why is not working? any error with the compilation?